# Why is catch (Exception) wrong?

Tags: c#, exception

I have read several times that using

```
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    Logger.LogError(ex);
}
```

without re throwing is wrong, because you may be hiding exceptions that you don't know about from the rest of the code.

However, I am writing a WCF service and am finding myself doing this in several places in order to ensure that the service does not crash. (SOA states that clients should not know or care about internal service errors since they unaware of the service implementation)

For instance, my service reads data from the file system. Since the file system is unpredictable I am trapping all exceptions from the read code. This might be due to bad data, permission problems, missing files etc etc. The client doesn't care, it just gets a "Data not available" response **and the real reason is logged in the service log**. I don't care either, I just know there was a problem reading and I don't want to crash.

Now I can understand there may be exceptions thrown unrelated to the file system. eg. maybe I'm out of memory and trying to create a read buffer has thrown an exception. The fact remains however, that the memory problem is still related to the read. I tried to read and was unable to. Maybe there is still enough memory around for the rest of the service to run. Do I rethrow the memory exception and crash the service even though it won't cause a problem for anything else?

I do appreciate the general idea of only catching exceptions you can deal with, but surely if you have an independent piece of code that can fail without affecting anything else, then it's ok to trap any errors generated by that code? Surely it's no different from having an app wide exception handler?

**EDIT: To clarify, the catch is not empty, the exception is logged. Bad example code by me, sorry. Have changed now.**

Comment: You said "the real reason is logged in the service log" - now that's exactly the problem - if you catch errors without doing anything with it, it won't be logged anywhere.

Comment: If the file system is unreliable, why are you catching exception and not just IO related exceptions?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Not sure if we're talking at cross purposes. I am logging the problem in the service log, therefore it is logged. :-?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: As I said, the read code can fail for any reason without affecting the rest of the service, not just IO problems.

Comment: You mean your actual `catch` block is not empty? So can't see any problem with that.

Comment: How do you log it, if you use `catch(Exception){}`?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer I have updated the code example to show that you are calling a method, and don't just have a comment in there. I had to read the whole Q to see that it wasn't a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say that your service works as expected if there are permission problems on the disk. imho a service returning `"Data not available"` is even worse than a service returning "Error".

imagine that you are the user of your service. You make a call to it and it returns "No data". You know that you're call is correct, but since you don't get any data you'll assume that the problem is yours and go back investigating. Lots of hours can be spent in this way.

Which is better? Treating the error as an error, or lie to your users?

**Update**

What the error depends on doesn't really matter. Access problems should be dealt with. A disk that fails sometimes should be mirrored etc etc. SOA puts more responsibilities on you as a developer. Hiding errors doesn't make them go away.

SOA should pass errors. It may not be a detailed error, but it should be enough for the client to understand that the server had a problem. Based on that, the client may try again later on, or just log the error or inform the service desk that a manual action might need to be taken.

If you return "No data", you won't give your users a chance to treat the error as they see fit.

**Update2**

I do use catch all in my top level. I log exceptions to the event log (which is being monitored).

Your original question didn't have anything in the catch (which it do now). It's fine as long as you remember to monitor that log (so that you can correct those errors).

Comment: "Which is better? Treating the error as an error, or lie to your users?" - I like that line

Comment: But it's not a lie, the data the client requested is not available. It might be because it's not there, it might be because it's corrupt, or it might be because the service threw some other exception whilst accessing. Any way it isn't available to the client. However I do understand your point. Maybe I misunderstand SOA which I thought discouraged passing errors to the client.

Comment: That sentence is simply wrong: Because you're not treating the error and because you need not lie to your users. By rethrowing the error you're giving your user some cryptic information that he doesn't know anything to do with. You're leaving him puzzled and insecure. THAT is wrong! By catching the error, logging him and telling your user a custom message like: "Sorry there's a problem, we've noted the issue and will try to resolve it as soon as possible, you can reach us at phone or by e-mail if you require further support" you're doing it exactly the right, user-friendly way.

Comment: @jgauffin: OK thanks, that helps my understanding of SOA. However, even if I pass "error" back to the client instead of "no data", it doesn't really affect my original question of whether catching all exceptions rather than specific exceptions is wrong? Surely the client wants an "error" no matter WHAT goes wrong, not just exceptions I can think of?

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to adopt this strategy you are going to make it very hard for deployment teams to work out why the client fails to work.  At the minimum log something somewhere.

Comment: I am logging: "the real reason is logged in the service log"

Comment: The catch isn't empty. Sorry, my bad explanation / example.

Answer (score 2):

One of the main issues becomes that *you will never know* that something went wrong. It isn't only your clients / consumers that have the error hidden from them, it is you as the service developer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no problem with that code. Make sure the user gets a nice message, like "Data not available due to an internal problem. The issue has been logged and the problem will be dealt with." And everybody's fine.

It's only a problem if you eat and swallow the exception so that nobody in the world will ever fix it.

Exceptions need always to be dealt with, either by writing special code or by just fixing the path that results in the exception. You can't always anticipate all errors, but you can commit to fixing them as soon as you become aware of them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the idea is to prevent missing errors.  Consider this: The service returns fine but is not doing as expected.  You have to go and search through event logs, file logs etc. to find a potential error.  If you put a trace write in there, you can identify hopefully the cause, but likely the area of hte issue and a timestamp to correlate errors with other logs.

If you use .NET Trace, you can implement in code and not turn it on until required.  Then to debug you can turn it on without having to recompile code.

WCF Services can use FaultException to pass exceptions back to the client. I have found this useful when building a WCF n-tier application server.

Answer (score 0):

It's commendable to ensure that your service does not crash, in a production environment. When debugging, you need the application to crash, for obvious reasons.

However, from your explanations, I get the impression that you're catching the exceptions you expect to be thrown, and catch the rest with an empty catch block, meaning you'll never know what happened.

It's correct to catch all exceptions as a last resort, but please log those too, they are no less interesting than those you expected. After catching and logging all exceptions related to network, I/O, security, authentication, timeout, bad data, whatever, log the rest.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can say that every exception occurs in a specific circumstance. For debugging purposes it is usefull to have as much information as possible about the failure so the person who is about to fix the bug know where to look and can fix the code in a minimum amount of time, which save his boss some money.

Besides that, throwing and catching specific exceptions will make your code more readable/understable and easier to maintain. Catching a general exception will fail on this point in every point of view. Therefore, also make sure that, when throwing an exception, that is is well documented (e.g. in XML comments so the caller knows the method can throw the specific exception) and has a clear name on what went wrong. Also include only information in the exception that is directly related to the problem (like id's and such).

Answer (score 0):

In vb.net, a somewhat better approach would be "Catch Ex As Exception When Not IsEvilException(Ex)", where "IsEvilException" is a Boolean function which checks whether Ex is something like OutOfMemoryException, ExecutionEngineException, etc.  The semantics of catching and rethrowing an exception are somewhat different from the semantics of leaving an exception uncaught; if a particular "catch" statement would do nothing with the exception except rethrow "as is", it would be better not to catch it in the first place.

Since C# does not allow exception filtering, you're probably stuck with a few not-very-nice choices:

1. Explicitly catch and rethrow any "evil" types of exceptions, and then use a blanket catch for the rest

   Catch all exceptions, rethrow all the evil ones "as-is", and then have your logic handle the rest

   Catch all exceptions and have your logic handle them without regard for the evil ones, figuring that if the CPU is on fire it will cause enough other exceptions to be raised elsewhere to bring the program down before persistent data gets corrupted.

One problem with exception handling in both Java and .net is that it binds tightly three concepts which are actually somewhat orthogonal:

1. What condition or action triggered the exception

   Should the exception be *acted upon*

   Should the exception be considered *resolved*

Note that sometimes an exception will involve two or more types of state corruption (e.g. an attempt was made to update an object from information at a stream, and something goes wrong reading the stream, leaving both the stream and the object being updated in bad states).  Code to handle *either* condition should act upon the exception, but the exception shouldn't be considered resolved until code for *both* has been run.  Unfortunately, there is no standard pattern for coding such behavior.  One could add a virtual read-only "Resolved" property to any custom exceptions one implements, and rethrow any such exceptions if "Resolved" returns false, but no existing exceptions will support such a property.

Answer (score -1):

If something is wrong, then it is wrong. It should crash.

You can never assure proper operations if something is crashing in the code. Even if that means that a page/form will always crash as soon as it is visited, you can never assure that things will keep working, or any changes be functionally committed.

And if a data resource crashes and instead returns a resource with 0 entries, the user will just be incredibly confused by something not returning any results when there should be obvious results. Valueable time will be spent by the user trying to find out what (s)he did wrong.

The only times I would recommend catching all exceptions (and logging them, not ignoring them), is if the code that is being ran is from plugins/compiled code from users, or some weird COM library, that you have no control over yourself.

Comment: What you say is so wrong by itself! If something is wrong there's absolutely NO necessity for it to crash: There's necessity that the error gets fixed! This however only requires that someone gets informed on the error and logging is absolutely fine for that. All you do by crashing your app is putting the burden on informing you of the error on the user and I'm sure NO user likes to carry that burden! If the user gets a nice problem-notification instead of a serious crash-down then the user will be soo much happier. I hate nothing more than things that totally fail on me.

Comment: I was being deliberately harsh since it is better to state the harsh version and let it be modified depending on the application than stating a loose version. What I meant was that you should always let the CURRENT exception be thrown. How it is handled at the absolute root level is up to the programmer: display a nice error message or show an automatic reporting tool; just not continue with the regular page/form operation. Just that you should not eat the exception where it happens.

But thanks for the downvote, will teach me to be more clear in my answers.